# Check if a string contains numbers and letters

Tags: php

I want to detect if a string contains both numbers and letters.

For example:

- Given `PncC1KECj4pPVW`, it would be written to a text file because it contains both.
- Given `qdEQ`, it would not, because it only contains letters.

Is there a method to do this?

I was trying to use

```
$string = PREG_REPLACE("/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/i", '', $buffer);
```

But it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [a-zA-Z] with a /i modifier is something of a tautology

Comment: @MarkBaker for when you want to make _sure_ it's case insensitive :)

Comment: Are non-alphanumeric characters allowed to be in the string?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Za-z]/', $myString))
{
    echo 'Secure enough';
}
```

Answer updated based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/9336130/315550, thnx to https://stackoverflow.com/users/116286/jb

Comment: @Duncan, This will only work if letters come before numbers. Won't work for `9877abc`.

Comment: Yes, @jb and JonathanM are both right. I +1ed her comment. I prefer the first solution of jb below (The 3th answer)

Comment: @MohammadNaji If you prefer someone else's answer over your own because people have pointed out a flaw in yours, why not improve your own? Especially given it's the accepted one.

Comment: Wow, this answer is so bad.

Answer (score 59):

It seems the simplest way is just to do it in two regex's.

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $myString) && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $myString))
{
    echo 'Contains at least one letter and one number';
}
```

I suppose another way to do it is this below. It says "a letter and then later on at some point a number (or vice versa)". But the one above is easier to read IMO.

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Za-z]/', $myString))
{
    echo 'Contains at least one letter and one number';
}
```

Comment: I've not downvoted, but your 1st and 2nd solutions will match "000  aaaa  111", which I suppose should be considered not valid (only "000aaaa111" etc., the string shouldn't contain other chars than alphanumeric) - however the OP did not specify that "000 aaaa 111" should be considered invalid, but the given examples are suggesting that behavior.

Comment: @FrostyZ you are quite right but the question does not say that it should contain no other chars. I answered the question as written.

Comment: @FrostyZ, the OP didn't give it as a requirement that other characters are not allowed. I read it that they are. I suppose they are allowed until specified otherwise. You really can't go by the single example, or you'd have to say that numbers must come after letters, too.

Comment: @Jonathan Yep, asking Duncan for precisions is the right thing to do. I was just guessing here.

Comment: @FrostyZ I agree. If no non-alphanumerics is a requirement, yours will work nicely. Though you should add capital letters.

Answer (score 8):

This works cleanly:

```
$myString="abc123";
if( preg_match('([a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-zA-Z])', $myString) ) 
{ 
    echo('Has numbers and letters.');
} else {
    echo("no");
}
```

To see it in action, copy it and paste it here: http://phptester.net/index.php?lang=en

Comment: This works for letters-then-numbers, or numbers-then-letters. However, it allows other characters (since you didn't say to exclude them in the post).

Comment: Updated for non-alphanumerics.

Comment: Your non-alphanumericas version has left me wanting. What if I want a number in the middle?

Comment: It "works" because it doesn't consume the entire string. `ab!c1` returns true because it'll only match `c1`. Though I do love that phptester site, so thank you for showing me that.

Comment: @jb. Good catch. More noodling to be done if that's a requirement. Removed.

Answer (score 7):

My only question is whether is had to be one regexp. I'd go with two or three (because you have to build a little complex regexp to do it at once.

Let's say that you require to have:

- at least one upper case character `[A-Z]`
- at least one lower case character `[a-z]`
- at least one number `\d`
- have password at least 7 characters long

The easiest and the most effective solution:

```
if( preg_match( '~[A-Z]~', $password) &&
    preg_match( '~[a-z]~', $password) &&
    preg_match( '~\d~', $password) &&
    (strlen( $password) > 6)){
    echo "Good password";
} else {
    echo "Not so much";
}
```

Otherwise, in one regexp you will have to consider several options:

- `[a-z][A-Z]+\d`
- `[a-z]\d+[A-Z]`
- `[A-Z][a-z]+\d`
- `[A-Z]\d+[a-z]`
- `\d[a-z]+[A-Z]`
- `\d[A-Z]+[a-z]`

Join it into one big and hardly readable "ored" regexp like:

```
~([a-z][A-Z]+\d|[a-z]\d+[A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]+\d|[A-Z]\d+[a-z]|\d[a-z]+[A-Z]|\d[A-Z]+[a-z])~
```

Of course you can go with (when needing just check upper and lower case):

```
preg_match( '~([a-z][A-Z]|[a-z][A-Z])~');
```

And still have to check length manually. The second solution seems pretty ineffective and hard to read to me. My recommendation: go with the first one.

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a built-in function for this. It's called [`ctype_alnum`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php).

```
if(!ctype_alnum($string)) {
  return $error;
}
// Continue on your way...
```

Comment: This is a great function.  However, it doesn't answer the OP because it only checks if the string contains letters or numbers.  It doesn't validate if the string contains both.

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect.  I hate it went incorrect answers are upvoted. https://3v4l.org/MNIt8

Comment: Misleading answer. It checks if ALL characters are Latin letter or digits. What if string (eg password) also contain some special characters? Or characters from non-latin alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match *only* alphanumeric chars (that is, consider the string as invalid as soon as there is anything else into it, like spaces or special characters), this should work.

Otherwise, just remove the first `preg_match()`.

```
function myTest($string)
{
  echo "test '".$string."': "
    . intval(preg_match('/^[a-z\d]+$/i', $string) // has only chars & digits
        && preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $string)        // has at least one char
        && preg_match('/\d/', $string))          // has at least one digit
    . "\n";
}

myTest('aAa'); // => 0
myTest('111'); // => 0
myTest('aAa111bbb'); // => 1
myTest('111aAabbb'); // => 1
myTest('aAabbb111'); // => 1
myTest('111bBb222'); // => 1
myTest('111 bBb 222'); // => 0
myTest('$$$$'); // => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

for checking if string contains numbers or not !!

```
function ContainsNumbers($String){
    return preg_match('/\\d/', $String) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support multiple languages, from PHP 5.1 additional escape sequences were added for the character types [listed here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

The following functions take advantage of this and allow you to check for letters and numbers in multiple alphabets:

check any letter exists in string:

```
function has_letter($x){
    if (preg_match("/[\p{L}]/u",$x)) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

check string contains any number

```
function has_number($x) {
    if (preg_match("/[\p{N}]/u",$x)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Usage

```
$string = '123اختبا';
has_letter($string); // true


$string = '೪౨౨'; 
has_number($string); // true
```

Both together as requested

```
$string='I am 28';
if (has_letter($string)&&has_number($string)){
    // true
}

$string='I am ౨೩೫';
if (has_letter($string)&&has_number($string)){
    // true
}

$string='Привет, друг, как ты?';
has_number($string); // false - this Russian text doesn't contain a number
```

Comment: The character class (square braces) are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers are whack... I'm fan of shortest, cleanest solution. This is my basic library that I updated and improved over 20 years while making games. Yes PHP has some built in functions to check some of this stuff, but I like simple, short word functions.

Here are 2 examples, both do the exact same thing using my functions

```
$fullname = abcSpc($_POST['fullname']) ? $_POST['fullname'] : false;
// Same As
if(abcSpc($_POST['fullname']){ $fullname=$_POST['fullname']; } else { $fullname=false; }
```

My Library

```
// BASIC FUNCTIONS, JAYY's LIBRARY
function abc ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z]+$/i', $input); }
function abcSpc ($input){ return preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z\ ]*$/i', $input); }
function abcNum ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i', $input); }
function abcNumSpc ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9\ ]+$/i', $input); }
function abcNumU ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9_-]+$/i', $input); }
function abcNumD ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9-]+$/i', $input); }
function num ($input){ if(strlen($input) > 24){ $input=0; }if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $input)){ $input=0; } return $input; }
function numU ($input){ return preg_match('/^[0-9_-]+$/i', $input); }
function is_odd($num){ return($num & 1); }
function email ($input){ return filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); }
function is_url($input){ return preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}'.'((:[0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$/i',$input); }
function is_uri ($input){ return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i', $input); }
```

U = Underline, D = Dash...

NOTE: num() checks for length of string due to a player 5-10 years ago discovering that if you type in a very large number, it actually breaks the num() and produces a string that isn't just numbers. You can either remove it or learn from my experience. That player ended up getting millions of free war units which destroyed the round for that game. Was not fun figuring out what he did.

I hope this helps someone. This is my first post, I don't normally get involved. I just like reading and learning from other peoples mistakes. Feel free to improve my library for me if you guys see room for improvements.

Comment: `[0-9]` is more simply `\d`.  `$input = 0;` is weird; that should be `return false;`. There is nothing to make case-insensitive in `/^[0-9_-]+$/i`.  `.` and a literal space inside of a character class do not need to be escaped to be treated literally. `(http|https)` is more simply `https?`. `($num & 1)` doesn't need parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The following func checks and returns TRUE if string contains alphabetic characters (not only from Latin alphabet, Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew and others are supported too) AND if it contain numeric characters (digits). Both digits and non-digit (but alphabetic) characters required for the function to return TRUE.

```
function is_good_string($s) {
    return preg_match('/\w/u', $s, $dummy) && // any alphabetic unicode character
           preg_match('/\d/', $s, $dummy) && // AND digit
           preg_match('/\D/', $s, $dummy); // AND non-digit
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hey here are some guidelines below:

Issue:  No validation on the digit inside the string
For e.g.

```
 OM  4  OM,   OM4OM   ,  space  OM 4  OM  space,  space  OM4OM space. -----> No valdation over this??
```

Solution:

```
if (preg_match("/[A-Za-z].*[0-9]/",$_POST["name"]))
    {
     header("location:http://localhost/Test1.html");
     exit;
    }
Logic:  /[A-Za-z].*[0-9]/
```

It says first characters and then at some point numbers.