# Input validation PHP

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, password-protection

I have a very basic php form I am looking to update.

Its used for registering a new user on a web application.

The issue is lack of validation, passwords can be any length using an characters.

Can any one help or point me in the right direction as to how I can enforce a minimum password length or complexity on the form?

The code is:

```
<h1>Register</h1>

<p>Please enter your details below to register.</p>

<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform" id="registerform">
<fieldset>
    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: it depends one what characters you want to enforce for the passwords

Comment: Well, your form is processed by file `register.php` according to your own code. So I suggest that in there you simply implement the checks you want to apply.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a retarded example that forces a password to have at least one uppercase, lowercase and a digit number.. just to get you started

```
<?php 

$pass1 = 'adsda';
$pass2 = 'asds3q3';
$pass3 = 'adsDd2d';

function pass_complexity($pass, $len) {
    $c = []; 
    $array =  str_split($pass); 
    foreach ($array as $l) {
        if (ctype_digit($l)) {
            $c['d'] = 1; 
        }

        if (ctype_upper($l)) {
            $c['u'] = 1; 
        } 

        if (ctype_lower($l)) {
            $c['l'] = 1; 
        }   
    }

    return strlen($pass) >= $len && count($c) == 3; 
}


if (pass_complexity($pass3, 2)) {
    echo 'password ok';
} else {
 // password should have at least 1 upper, 1 lower 1 number and 
 // and must be at least more than 2 digits in length  
}
```

All you have to do is call `pass_complexity()` function, the first argument takes the password, the second the string length limit

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread for character validation on your password string:

[Check if a string contains numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335915/check-if-a-string-contains-numbers-and-letters)

And for the string length:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php