# How to user pregmatch in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find if a persons name contains any numbers or symbols. I am not very sure how to use preg_match and all the examples online make no sense can someone please explain how i can check if a value has numbers or symbols. And if you can please explain how it works.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems this question has plenty of usable answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335915/check-if-a-string-contains-numbers-and-letters

Comment: Please provide some example inputs and what you expect the output to be for each of those cases. Give examples of matches and non-matches. *"symbols"* is a very vague term. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the person name contains only number. The code below has been tested and is working

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

    $number = '001222288';
    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $number)) {
        //error
echo 'Error does not contain only number';
    } else {
        echo 'success. it contains only number';
    }
?>
```

if the variable number contains any other thing that is not number it result in error. eg

```
$number = 'ABFRT001222288';
```

To check for alphabets or string

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

    $string = 'ABTYUUU';
    if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z]*$/', $string)) {
        //error
echo 'Error does not contain only alphabet';
    } else {
        echo 'success. it contains only alphabets';
    }
?>
```

Mark this as correct answer if it solve your problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function [preg_match](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) use regex expressions. You can use an online tool for test your regex. I use [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), preg_match use PCRE expressions. In your case you should, you may use for numbers
`preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $subject);`

EDIT : We need more details for the symbols you want select