# Require both text and numbers in address field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

In the address fields for WooCommerce people tend to forget to put in a housenumber, so to fix this I used a code that requires them to input numbers in the address field.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validation_process');
 
function custom_validation_process() 
{
    global $woocommerce;
 
    if(isset($_POST['billing_address_1']) and $_POST['billing_address_1'] != '')
    {
        if (!preg_match('/([0-9]+)/Uis', $_POST['billing_address_1']))
        {
            if(function_exists('wc_add_notice'))
                wc_add_notice( __('Om het pakket te bezorgen hebben we ook een huisnummer nodig. Voeg deze toe in het adresveld.'), 'error' );
            else
                $woocommerce->add_error( __('Om het pakket te bezorgen hebben we ook een huisnummer nodig. Voeg deze toe in het adresveld.') );
        }
    }
   
    if(isset($_POST['ship_to_different_address']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['shipping_address_1']) and $_POST['shipping_address_1'] != '')
        {
            if (!preg_match('/([0-9]+)/Uis', $_POST['shipping_address_1']))
            {
                if(function_exists('wc_add_notice'))
                    wc_add_notice( __('Om het pakket te bezorgen hebben we ook een huisnummer nodig. Voeg deze toe in het adresveld.'), 'error' );
                else
                    $woocommerce->add_error( __('Om het pakket te bezorgen hebben een ook je huisnummer nodig. Voeg deze toe in het adresveld.') );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It worked for sometime but I am starting to notice some people are now not forgetting the housenummer but the street name as well. The field itself is required of itself but I need to force them to put in both text and numbers.

Can anybody help me out in how to add a text requirement to this code next to the numbers?

Comment: Have you tried 1 or more of the following answers? [Check if a string contains numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335915/check-if-a-string-contains-numbers-and-letters)

Comment: I tried changing (!preg_match('/([0-9]+)/Uis', $_POST['billing_address_1']) to (!preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/Uis', $_POST['billing_address_1']) but that did not work. It even made numbers not a requirement anymore

Comment: I tried some of the others as well, but was these seem to do is either require a-z of 0-9 not both of them